# Specify table style changes with checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

Is there a way that I can change the style of a selected row, to whatever with a checkbox selection. The styles will change for the selected rows when the "click me" button is selected. I am able to delete the rows (with another button), but not change the styles of the selected rows. The rows will either be deleted or the style will change.

Can someone assist me, or show me in the right direction for the styling issue?

HTML:

```
<input class="dent" type="button" value="style">
<input class="delBtn" type="button" value="Delete">

<table>
  <tr>
  <td style="width: 20px;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="chk">
   </td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>

  </tr><br>
  <tr>
  <td style="width: 20px;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="chk">
   </td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>

  </tr><br>
  <tr>
  <td style="width: 20px;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="chk">
   </td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>

  </tr><br>
  <tr>
  <td style="width: 20px;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="chk">
   </td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>

  </tr><br>
</table>
```

JS to delete a row

```
function delBoxes() {
   let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chk');
   for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
     let box = boxes[i];
     if (box.checked) {
       let rowTag = box.parentNode.parentNode;
       let tableTag = box.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
       tableTag.removeChild(rowTag);
     }
   }
}

document.getElementById("deleteButton").addEventListener("click", delBoxes);
```

Comment: What do you mean the styling will change? There is no style changing logic in the code you've shared.

Comment: He means to change the style to any style (changing just the color should be ok)

Comment: You could toggle a class on your table element

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few changes to your HTML, adding ID's for the buttons and rows. Also I added data-sets to the check boxes so you can know which rows to execute the task (change style or remove)

```js
function delBoxes() {
   let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chk');
   for (let i = boxes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     let box = boxes[i];
     if (box.checked) {
       let rowTag = document.getElementById(box.dataset.row);
       rowTag.parentNode.removeChild(rowTag);
     }
   }
}

function style() {
   let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chk');
   for (let i = boxes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     let box = boxes[i];
     if (box.checked) {
       let rowTag = document.getElementById(box.dataset.row);
       rowTag.style.backgroundColor = "red";
     }
   }
}

document.getElementById("deleteButton").addEventListener("click", delBoxes);
document.getElementById("styleButton").addEventListener("click", style);
```

```html
<input class="dent" type="button" value="style" id="styleButton">
<input class="delBtn" type="button" value="Delete" id="deleteButton">

<table>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td style="width: 20px;">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" data-row="row1">
     </td>
    <td><input type="text" value="I am 1"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td style="width: 20px;">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" data-row="row2">
     </td>
    <td><input type="text"  value="I am 2"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td style="width: 20px;">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" data-row="row3">
     </td>
    <td><input type="text" value="I am 3"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row4">
    <td style="width: 20px;">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" data-row="row4">
     </td>
    <td><input type="text" value="I am 4"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```